# Publish a value of a C program to a webpage

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, html

I have built some sensors around my Raspberry Pi. With a C++ program, I can read out the SPI bus to get the sensor values. What i want to do now is to publish these values to a simple web page (php, html or whatever). I have installed LAMP on the Pi and successfully published a simple web page in my personal network.

So the 'only thing' that is left is to make a connection between an html page and my C++ program, but I have no idea how to do it. So the question is, am I on the right track, and how can it be done? I am not able to find a 'simple' solution and don't know where to begin.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html

Comment: You should avoid mixing up things. Is it a C or a C++ program?

Comment: Take a moment to understand the basic pipeline you can adopt to satisfy your requirements by reading: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html#behindscenes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand some of [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP)

You could make your C program a web server using some HTTP server library like e.g. [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/), [mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) (as commented by [oysteijo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1659500/oysteijo)), [libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/)  etc... (in C++ consider also [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt)). Then your application would provide a web page.

You could make your C program a web client using some HTTP client library like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). Then your application would e.g. fill a web form located elsewhere. (your C program could also e.g. be database client and some other Web server would access the same database and display the data).

You could also consider making your C program a [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) or [FastCgi](http://fastcgi.com/) application (interacting with a web server like [Lighttpd](http://lighttpd.net/) or Apache...)

Comment: I don't get point 3. What would making the program be a client help?

Comment: Good answer, Basile. If this is a simple publishing of one value at a Raspberry Pi with limited resources, I would rather consider [mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) instead of [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/).

Comment: @oysteijo: In my experience `libonion` is very light (but I admit I never saw a Raspberry Pi.)

Comment: Hi all, thanks a lot for helping! It took some time to test them all, and it turned out that mongoose was the best/easiest solution for me. I have now a simple program to readout the sensors with an update frequency of 1 second and publish the result on a simple webpage. Thanks a lot!